# Subclassing NSLayoutConstraint constant based on screen height

Tags: ios, swift, subclass, nslayoutconstraint, iphone-x

I have a project with a Tab Bar, and a custom Navigation bar for each of the tabs. Each of the Navigation bar UIViews have a height constraint constant set in the storyboard.

I would like to subclass this NSLayoutConstraint (for the Nav height), so that it changes the height for iPhone X. The Navigation bar needs to be much taller on an iPhone X, and since I'm not using "out of the box" objects, my constraints need to be manually set.

Essentially, I want to do something like the following in the subclass, so I don't have to repeat a bunch of code and make unnecessary outlets:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    navBarHeightConstraint.constant = navBarHeightConstraintConstant()
}

func navBarHeightConstraintConstant() -> CGFloat {
    switch(UIScreen.main.bounds.height) {
    case 812: // iPhone X
        return 90
    default: // all others
        return 64
    }
}
```

I have created the subclass, but don't know what methods to use to perform the above code.

```
class NavHeightFixiPhoneXConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {

    // Nothing... yet!

}
```

**How can I subclass NSLayoutConstraint so that it displays a specific value for just iPhone X?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can override the constant variable:

```
final class NavHeightFixiPhoneXConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {

    override var constant: CGFloat {
        set {
            super.constant = newValue
        }
        get {
           return navBarHeightConstant()
        }
    }

    private func navBarHeightConstant() -> CGFloat {
        switch (UIScreen.main.bounds.height) {
         case 812:
            return 90
         default: 
             return 64
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wait, I just get "Cannot override mutable property with read-only property 'constant'" ...

Comment: You are right ;) the property has getter and setter so you need to provide both. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Right - I figured it in the meantime!  :)

Comment: I have created the same custom class for my purpose but this method is not being called at all.

Comment: Works fine, and I even made it a @IBDesignable :-)

Comment: `layoutIfNeeded()` in `navBarHeightConstant()` will never be reached

Comment: @schmidt9 Good catch, I wrote this from my mobile phone a long time ago, also I missed the return in the function signature and the layoutIfNeeded function is not present in a NSLayoutConstraint subclass! Thanks :)