# Subclassing NSLayoutConstraint in Swift

Tags: swift, inheritance, nslayoutconstraint, subclassing

I want to subclass `NSLayoutConstraint` in Swift to provide easier ways for instantiating common constraints (for example `height`, `width`, ...).

The code-draft I've written so far does not work properly, because the `item`-properties are inaccessible for writing:

```
class TestConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {
    init(item: Any) {
        super.init()
        self.firstItem = item // WARNING: Cannot assign to property: 'firstItem' is a get-only property

        // ...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to subclass `NSLayoutConstraint` in this way or do I have to take other things additionally into account?

Comment: Have you tried layout anchors ?. It is the preferred way. Don’t subclass it

Comment: That's much easier, thank you.

Comment: if you **really do** want to customzie constraints, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46867981/294884

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is an extension of UIView.

```
extension UIView{
    func anchor(top:NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?,leading:NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?,trailing:NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?,bottom:NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?,padding:UIEdgeInsets = .zero,size:CGSize = .zero){

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        if let top = top{
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: padding.top).isActive = true
        }
        if let leading = leading{
            leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading, constant: padding.left).isActive = true
        }
        if let trailing = trailing{
            trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing, constant: -padding.right).isActive = true
        }
        if let bottom = bottom{
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -padding.bottom).isActive = true
        }
        if size.width != 0{
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width).isActive = true
        }
        if size.height != 0{
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height).isActive = true
        }
    }

}
```